# Can I use a shortcut key to select the hex code box?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shortcuts

I'm trying to set up a macro key to Color Panel for use hex codes easily. F6 key opens the Color Panel but how can I activate the hex code box with a shortcut key? I know, it's a weird question. All I want is to use 4 macro functions: [F6], [???], [Ctrl+V], [Enter]. I need to remove the mouse click part. How can select this box with a shortcut key? Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut, or ability to add a shortcut, which will focus on a field within any panel in Illustrator.

You *may* be able to use scripting to perform your steps.

Comment: Thank you for the time saving answer.